# How to deal with accents in Active Directory Filters with Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I'll try to keep this very concise :

I have written a java webapp that allows user searches by name. You type a part of the name and it returns a list of all the users it matches.

```
 searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" + name + "*))";
```

I work in a french environment and a lot of the names have accents, mostly "é" but sometimes other letters too (ö, ï, è, etc...). The problem is that some people are registered in AD with their name having accents, some are stripped.

i.e. : Two users both named Éric, one was registered as Éric and the other as Eric.

When name = "Eric", only users without the accent are returned and vice versa, when name = "Éric" only users with the accent are returned. I'm looking for a behavior where typing either "Eric" or "Éric" would return all Éric and Eric results combined.

My solution is less than ideal and I'm looking for something more reliable but I can't find anything :

```
searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" + stripAccents(name) + "*))";

public static String stripAccents(String s) 
{
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", ""); //remove all accents
    s = s.replaceAll( "e|i|o", "*" ); //replace e, i ,o with wildcard
    System.out.print( s );
    return s;
}
```

This solution obviously gives me more results than intended because of the many wildcards added.

Just replacing all accented letters with a wildcard wouldn't work because searching for "Eric" wouldn't return "Éric" results.

Comment: Considering e without and with diacritical marks: could you not replace each of e, é, è and ê with [eéèê], [eé], [eè], and [eê] respectively to provide consistent matches?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I believe ldap filters only support wildcard and not regex. I don't know if there is another way around though.

Comment: I could have used a one letter wildcard like "?" if it was implanted in ldap filters that would do the job better than "*".

Comment: If the results are passed back to the Java program you could post-process these using full regex power. Having just '*' and '?' wildcards is inane.

Comment: Actually there isn't even a "?" wilcard. I will try your solution, right now I'm trying something even messier. I'm doing an OR search with all possible case.. searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(givenName=*éric*)(givenName=*eric*)(givenName=*èric*)(givenName=*êric*)(givenName=*érïc*)(givenName=*erïc*)(givenName=*èrïc*)(givenName=*êrïc*)(givenName=*érîc*)(givenName=*erîc*)(givenName=*èrîc*)(givenName=*êrîc*)))"; and that's not even all..I don't think this is right but it'll work.

Comment: No Frenchman worth his salt would use "êric" for "eric", and other variants don't make sense to me either.

Comment: Well it's weird for the name Eric but there are some people with Forêt, Noël, Lefèbvre as family name where I work. Again some are registered as Foret and some as Forêt...since I have no way of knowing all the names and variations, I'm trying to substitute all "e" with all the variations possible.

Comment: With family names it's definitely more difficult. Although, an 'ë' doesn't make sense except after a vowel, and there are limits for the use of 'ê' as well: before 't' it indicates the lost 's' ("forestis (silva)"). But I'm not really an expert!

Comment: I totally agree but I didn't want to code any languages rules..I checked a bunch of names from our AD and some have really "non-common" spelling (sorry if I insult anyone) and we have around 20k employees so it's impossible to treat all cases without a general rule.

Comment: I think your 'or' approach is the best solution here.  Sure it's a long string, but it's not like it needs to be human-readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Laune's idea in the comments, I tried changing all e,i,c to wildcards * and then filter the results. It goes like this :

1) I strip the accents from the name the user enters with java normalizer and change all e,i,c to wilcards

```
    public static String stripAccents(String s) 
{
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", ""); //remove all accents
    s = s.replaceAll( "(?i)e|i|c", "*" ); //replace e, i ,c with wildcard
    return s;
}
```

2) I execute the search in my code : This will give me tons of results I don't need, I use Eric as example since it contains 3 of the letters. The search is *r** which as expected return way too many results.

```
searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" + Util.stripAccents(name) +"*))";
```

3) Next I filter the results by passing each of them in a function that create a dynamic regex pattern based on the initial name entered for the search (I still have to test performance with the regex class in java). For Eric, the pattern would like like .*[eèéêëÉÈÊËE]r[iïîIÏÎ][cçCÇ].* .Then I check if the names obtained in the search matches the pattern one by one and keep the ones that does. (note the .* before and after are because I want to keep results like "Frederic".

```
public static boolean nameRessemble(String initialName, String name){      
    String pattern = initialName.replaceAll( "(?i)e|è|é|ê|ë", "[eèéêëÉÈÊËE]" );
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll( "i|ï|î", "[iïîIÏÎ]" );
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll( "c|ç", "[cçCÇ]" );
    boolean match= name.matches("(?i).*" + pattern +".*");
    return match;

}
```

When I loop through the results to display them, I simply add a condition :

```
 while ( ne.hasMoreElements() ) {
     if(nameRessemble( name, ne.next().getAttributes.get(NAME_FIELD)) {
         // display 
     }
 }
```

This is what I use for now, I will probably try a function that craft a searchFilter with all possible cases like in my comments. I couldn't properly do it yesterday because it becomes quite confusing. Performances are ok (<1-3 seconds loading compared to usual <1 second and depends on the number of wildcards added)